# Javascript - 3RD party API call only fails in some cases

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

I am calling an external API via Typescript/Javascript

```
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    httpsAgent: new https.Agent({
        rejectUnauthorized: false
    })
});

return await axiosInstance.get(`${baseUrl}/v1/cars/${carId}.json`, { params: { token: apiToken } });
```

Works great in test cases for all cases. But somehow when calling via an AWS LAMBDA when the JSON from the payload is a > 1000 lines or so, the data comes corrupted

[image]

Any idea what can be the issue? Like I said, works fine in unit tests, POSTMAN and works well when the response payload is smaller. It's not timeout because the call is done <1s.

Any idea???

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
return await axiosInstance.get(`${baseUrl}/v1/cars/${carId}.json`, { headers: { 'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json' }, params: { token: apiToken } });
```